# Arch: Java "ugly" font bug

Tags: arch-linux, java, fonts

I know this is a pretty common bug, however none of the solutions I could find helped me.

**Fonts are ugly in Java applications**

Here are two examples (Processing & PyCharm):

[image: Processing][image: PyCharm]
*(Astonishingly "Events" looks just fine here)*

As I mentioned above, there are many solutions out there, but none of them fixed the problem for me:

- Enabling [Anti-Aliasing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Better_font_rendering)
- Using [GTK LookAndFeel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#GTK_LookAndFeel)
- Installing [`fontconfig-infinality`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fontconfig-infinality/)
- Installing the [Oracle JDK](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk/) (instead of OpenJDK)
- Installing the [OpenJDK-Infinality](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk8-openjdk-infinality/) patch

**How can I fix the font rendering?**

Some useful (maybe?) information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux scriptim 4.10.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 12 18:50:28 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on, -Dswing.aatext=true
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on'` to your `/etc/environment` file.

If you are running java applications from console, add `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on'` to your `.bashrc` (if you run bash shell) or `.zshrc` (if you run Z shell).

Log out then log in again.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I've already tried *"Enabling Anti-Aliasing"*. I assume that I did not log in again at that time.